# History of 16 Teveis

Tags: jewish-date-series, history, calendar

****Looking for answers as to what happened in Jewish history on this date. It can include both positive and negative occurrences. It can also include birthdays or Yarzheits of well known personalities that happened on this date.**

**Please cite / link your sources, if possible.**

**All interesting answers will be up voted.**

***Best answer will be accepted.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Ulysses S. Grant was told to revoke Order No. 11, which was a command to expel all Jews from Tennessee, Kentucky and Mississippi.Grant who was the commander of U.S. Army forces, believed that Jews where smuggling cotton , and he decided to expel the Jews from southern territory. Grant wrote these words "No Jews are to be permitted to travel on the railroad southward from any point... The [region] must be purged of them." Grant's orders meant that Jews were expelled .Jews were denied rail transportation and had to go on foot. Those who did not  were thrown into jail. Jewish leaders  arranged a meeting with President Lincoln, who cancelled the expulsion order. Grant later become U.S. president and never gave an explanation or apology.
Summary of Aish.com Article

2)Emperor Joseph II of Austria issued an Edict of Toleration in 1782 which repealed some of the restrictions on Jews from the Church.It's intention was not the emancipation but their assimilation.Napoleon's and others later had similar plans and many times it worked and caused much Intermarriage.

3) It is known as the Baghdad Purim. The Turkish leader Sultan Murad IV conquered the city from other Persians with the help of the Jews. The day was celebrated as a Yom Ness.When the Ottomans ruled the city, at least early on life for its Jewish residents was better than the Persian Shiites who made life a challenge.

4)Yahertzits

-R' Aryeh Leibish of Vishnitza  known as "Rebbe Leibish Charif.descendant of the Megaleh Amukos, son-in-law of the Yismach Moshe and Talmid Muvhak of the Chozeh of Lublin. Mechaber of Aryeh Devei Iloy (Teshovous), Ari Shebachabura (Mesechta Kesubos) and Ateres Zekeinim Niftar in (1846)

-R' Chaim ben R' Avrohom Yosef Kreisworth Niftar in 2001